# Does the "Ignored Files" settings create an external ignore file for it's select VCS?

Tags: intellij-idea, gitignore

I assumed that if I have my VCS set up with Git and listed files within the "ignored files" settings, then IntelliJ Idea is automatically creating a .gitignore file. This doesn't appear to be the case.

My project has a .gitignore file and it does not match the settings within "Ignored Files". I suspect this is a failure on my part to understand what this IntelliJ setting is.

So Ignored Files has nothing to do with my gitignore file?

Answer (score 0):

Right: The "Ignore" feature of IDEA is separate from the specific version control ignore feature.

The IDEA help at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-ignored-files.html says

> If the version control system that you are using has its own ignore facilities, use the corresponding native command provided by the version control integration.

Unfortunately the git plugin currently does not have specific commands to deal with .gitignore files.

There is a plugin that deals with that (though I never tried it myself):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495

Interestingly, I have not found a feature request at IDEA's bug tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/). You may try to create a request there.